Exception when filtering not null and not empty sets
The method below is a method from JpaRepository:
@Query("select h from HistoricoInteracaoEntidade h " +
        "where h.cliente.id = :clienteId " +
        "and h.author in :authors " +
        "and h.isBlockedDueConvert = false " +
        "and h.descricao is not null " +
        "or (h.justificativas is not null and size(h.justificativas) > 0) " +
        "and h.moment > :conversionDateMinusDays " +
        "order by h.moment asc")
List<HistoricoInteracaoEntidade> getElegibleInteractions(
        @Param("clienteId") String clienteId,
        @Param("authors") List<InteracaoAuthor> authors,
        @Param("conversionDateMinusDays") LocalDateTime conversionDateMinusDays);

the problem is when I test this method it returns me:

UnsupportedOperationException

But when I remove condition
h.justificativas is not null and 

The exception is resolved. But it's a problem because sometimes I save the child entity (justificativas) as a null array instead empty.
If I switch the chunk
"or (h.justificativas is not null and size(h.justificativas) > 0) "

to
and h.justificativas is not null

the problem persists

Remember that the query you are writing in jpql is translated by Hibernate into an SQL native query, and then the condition is written as a condition that evaluates if a count on the justificativas relation is greater than 0. In this terms, you should not need the is not null condition, since it is not evaluated against the java entities but on the database counterparts record and relations.

I see, so null pointer exception like is not a big deal in hql?

When you're creating a hql query, the where clauses are not applied on the java entities, so there is no need to manage the null list cases. You are getting the above exception because justificativas is not a column in the table mapped by HistoricoInteracaoEntidade, so hibernate can't manage an is not null sql constraint on it.
